# My has_many - belongs_to tables in ruby on rails don't seem to be related.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite3-ruby

I made 'hospital_review' table and 'hospital_review_comments' table with 1:N relationship on ruby on rails.
'hospital_review' table's migration file is like this.

```
class CreateHospitalReviews < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
     create_table :hospital_reviews do |t|
       t.string :written_time
       t.string :writter
       t.integer :user_id
       t.string :category
       t.string :hospital_name 
       t.text :content
      end
   end
```

and 'hospital_review_comments's one is like this.

```
   def change
     create_table :hospital_review_comments do |t|
       t.integer :user_id
       t.integer :post_id
       t.string :writter
       t.string :written_time
       t.text :content

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
```

'hospital_review' table's model file is like this.

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :hospital_review_comments
```

'hospital_review_comments' table's one is like this.

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :hospital_review
```

I wanted to show each hospital review and the comments that are written on it, so I programmed the codes below in 'show.html.erb'.

```
<% @post.hospital_review_comments.each do |comment| %>
<p><strong><%=comment.user.username%></strong> <%=comment.content%></p>
```

and this is show action in controller file.

```
def show
@post = HospitalReview.find(params[:id])
@hospital_comment_writer = User.where(id: session[:user_id])[0]
end
```

but the error occcured with message

```
'SQLite3::SQLException: no such column:'.
```

I tried 'foregin_key' in hospital_review_comments table's model file, but it didn't work. I can't get the reason the error occurred. Plz help!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `hospital_review_id` in your hospital_review_comments table

Comment: I changed post_id to hospital_review_id, and. now it works! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think you have wrongly added `post_id` in hospital_review_comments table, which should be `hospital_review_id`, that will to the job.

Else you can add the `foreign_key` option in the association as follows.

> has_many :hospital_review_comments, foreign_key: 'post_id'